# Error log: avoid multiple logging of same error

Tags: logging

I hope someone can give me some useful suggestions about the question i'm going to describe.
My company software consists of different layers built for managing specific jobs.

Basically we have:

- Data access layer for database interface
- Transport layer for sending message over multiple protocol (ftp, smtp, mapi etc)
- Business layer (logic of our application)
- Other layers

We have adopted NLog as common framework for logging errors and activities of the various layers. Besides activities, which are logged indepently and correctly by each "layer", i would like to log an exception only 1 time in the layer/class where it happens. For example  the Business layer uses the Database layer into which some errors occours during SQL operation and the error logged by Database layer is logged again by the Business layer with result that the log file or email or whatever duplicate same error. I understand that logging a lot is better then no logging :-) but... do you have practical suggestions for trying to avoid multiple log of same exception?

Thanks in advance
Luigi

Comment: Does the software define custom exception wrappers for managing exceptions?

Comment: Yes, we have defined exception wrappers !